# App crashing in Kivy on Android

Tags: android, python, kivy

My app crashes when I try to save using screenshot.

Code: http://pastebin.com/uifMeiS1

Sorry for not much information, don't know what else to write.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is the logcat output when it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a known bug in the stable branch that has been resolved in master.

Solution; use the master branch, or wait a few days for a new stable version (coming very soon), or copy the new [export_to_png method](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L527) from the source into your own widget and use that. If you use it on the root widget it will have the same effect as screenshot, but uses a different mechanism that probably works fine.